# Reducing the size of a div container

Tags: html, css, joomla

Hello I was wondering how I would go about making my div container smaller in size in height but keep the text centered? Here is an image of it below.

[image: Contact Details]

My css so far for this div is,

```
.contactdet {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); // transparent white
    background: #fff; // Left as a fallback for older browsers
    color: #FFFFFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://www.webbmaster.com.au/web-programs/questdesign/index.php/contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you can remove the blank paragraphs above and below the text. If you inspect the element, you will see the following:

```
<div class="custom contactdet">
  <p> </p>
  <p style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="font-size: medium;">contact@questdesign.com.au ● (03) 9014 4882 ● 0413 859 064</span>
  </p>
  <p> </p>
</div>
```

You have 2 `<p>` tags with no content in them.

Once removed, you can add a small padding like so:

```
.custom.contactdet > p {
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstable clean your container. Remove both `<p>&nbsp;</p>` that are inside of `<div class="custom contactdet">`
After that just add 'height' and `line-height` to your class:

```
.contactdet {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); // transparent white
    background: #fff; // Left as a fallback for older browsers
    color: #FFFFFF;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `height` property

```
.contactdet {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); // transparent white
    background: #fff; // Left as a fallback for older browsers
    color: #FFFFFF;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:30px; /* Change this to the height you want*/
}
```

Comment: No good. When I did that it merges with the bottom div container. http://www.webbmaster.com.au/web-programs/questdesign/index.php/contact

Comment: Problem with this method is that it's not dynamic. If the font size was ever to change or more content was added in, the height would no adjust accordingly and would have to be manually changed again.

Comment: @Lodder Thats is true, but the OP asked to set a height. Adding padding, can still result in a taller footer if the content fills up. The OP did not mention the need of being dynamic. Of course using padding instead of fixed height is better.